# Populate object inside another class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a search object:

```
public class Search
    {

    [Display(Name = "First name:")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string fname { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Surname:")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string sname { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date to (dob):")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? dateT { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date from (dob):")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? dateF { get; set; }

    public Search()
    {
        /*
        first_name = string.Empty;
        surname = string.Empty;
        dateT = null;
        dateF = null;
        */            
    }
}
```

I've instantiated this in the following class:

```
public class MainModel
{

    public UserML userLM;

    public Search search;

    public MainModel()
    {
        userLM = new UserML();
        search = new Search();           
    }

}
```

The Main model is what i'm using my view to populate the search object but I keep getting null values on submission (placing break point in my controller)

Example field:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.search.fname)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.search.fname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.search.fname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Model passed to view:

```
WebApp1.MainModel
```

Is this possible? any ideas?

Seen this also:

[create-an-object-inside-another-class-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270512/create-an-object-inside-another-class-c)

Comment: refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7789986/3462759)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created **Fields** in the **Model** instead of **Properties** in the `MainModel` class, you need to expose them as properties by providing `get` and `set` so that these can be mutated by ModelBinder of MVC:

```
public class MainModel
{
    public UserML userLM {get;set;}  // note { get;set; }

    public Search search {get;set;}

     public MainModel()
     {
        userLM = new UserML();
        search = new Search();           
    }

}
```

This would now enable the Model Binder to properly bind the value back on form post, the model binding wouldn't work on Fields actually.

Comment: This has fixed the issue - as soon as I can accept, i'll do so. Thanks! (Also - don't know why I didn't realize this simple issue!)

Answer (score 0):

The default value for a string is null. You would need to explicitly state if you want them to be empty strings in the constructor of either your main model like so:

```
 public MainModel()
 {
    userLM = new UserML();
    search = new Search{
        fname = "", 
        //other properties           
 }
```

Or by doing this in the constructor of the search object itself.

Alternatively you could use field initializers in the Search class like so:

```
[Display(Name = "First name:")]
[DataType(DataType.Text)]
public string fname { get; set; } = ""
```

For the return binding, your fields on the Main model would have to be properties. You can make this so by adding the `{get; set;}` at the end of each field.